# Convert DGN to PDF

Tags: java, web-applications, command-line, jakarta-ee, autocad

How can I convert MicroStation (DGN) files to PDF via command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OpenDesign Alliance](http://www.opendesign.com/) has libraries for dgn and dwg with pdf capabilities.
You could could use them to create the command line utility.

Answer (score 0):

Decision Graphics http://www.dgnlink.com/ has a number of products that convert DGN to DWG, all of which can be run from a command line.

Once you have the DWG files, you can use one of the command line DWG to PDF converters (I can't recommend a specific one but a quick Google will find loads), or if you have a copy of AutoCAD or AutoCAD LT, you could write a script for that to convert the DWGs by using the DWG To PDF plotter.

Answer (score 0):

From command line parameters, you can not do it. But you can create a Visual Basic or VB.NET application that will lunch microstation to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this one for a long time. All of the existing tools out there require expensive per-user licenses, which was a no-go for my implementation.

I solved the issue with a combination of three things:

1. Downloaded Bentley Viewer. This is their 100% free viewing/printing application.
2. Set up a virtual Windows postscript printer using GhostScript and RedMon. There are various guides online for this, and it can be a bit tricky to track down all of the prerequisites, but it is quite stable once set up correctly. Here is one guide: [GhostScript/RedMon Guide](http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSPSprinter/GSPSprinter.html)
3. Use a "Key-In" script to pass print commands to Bentley View. This involves simply creating a text file with the required commands [(List of Commands)](http://docs.bentley.com/en/MicroStation/ustnhelp1515.html) and passing it AND the file you want to convert on the command line as such:

   **BentleyView.exe -M [Filename.dgn] -S[KeyIn FileName]**

   Please note that you need a space between the -M and the DGN filename but NOT between the -S and the Key-In script filename.

   The script I used to simply print the document and then quit the GUI was:

   ```
   PRINT PRINTERNAME PDFWriter
   PRINT EXECUTE
   QUIT
   ```

This is not a perfect solution at all, especially since it requires the installation of Bentley View and it also opens a UI when called (although it does close it immediately after printing).